# How to name Google App Engine deploys

Tags: google-app-engine

Currently each `gcloud app deploy` gets a unique ID.

Is there a way to provide an alias while deploying? It would help recognise the build in a more readable way in the Google console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `gcloud app deploy` command generates a version name based on the current timestamp. You can set a version name for your service when deploying it by using the [--version](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) (or -v) flag like this:

```
gcloud app deploy version=version_name
```